# Drawing an X shape with using only asteriks and recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Consider this code.

```
public static void patternMaker(int start, int max, int direction) {
    if (start == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (start == max) {
        direction = -1;
    }

patternMaker(start +direction, max, direction);
```

The output looks like this.

[image]

Where I need it to look like this

[image]

So I basically need the same thing but from the other side,and I need to move one space to the right and every new  line.I am not sure how to produce that,I've tried duplicating the direction to get the other part of the X but that did not work out.Also not sure how to move one space to the right every line,I'd assume id need to adjust the direction on every iteration but missing a good idea.Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the lines where you need to start "not on the left hand side" should start with spaces...

Comment: The desired output is not a one liner X, can you please explain, how it should be created? Or is a one liner X is viable solution?

Comment: Well it says it should be created with recursion,but the picture I posted is how its susposed to look

Comment: What is the rule that tells you how many of each symbol should appear, in order, on a given line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using recursion is required, here is a solution based on your provided code example:

I outsourced the printing-part into a separate method.

```java
public static void patternMaker(int max) {
  patternMaker(1, max, 1);
}

public static void patternMaker(int numOfStars, int max, int direction) {
  if (numOfStars == 0) {
    return;
  }

  if (numOfStars == max) {
    //print the maximum number of stars also before the middle
    printPatternLine(numOfStars, max, false); 

    //print middle part twice
    printPatternLine(numOfStars, max, true); 
    printPatternLine(numOfStars, max, true); 

    direction = -1;
  }
  printPatternLine(numOfStars, max, false);

  patternMaker(numOfStars + direction, max, direction);
}

private static void printPatternLine(int numOfStars, int max, boolean middle) {
  int spacesBefore;
  int spacesBetween;

  if(middle) {
    spacesBefore = numOfStars;
    spacesBetween = 0;
  } else {
    spacesBefore = numOfStars -1;
    if(numOfStars == max) {
      spacesBetween = 2;
    } else {
      spacesBetween = (max - numOfStars) * 4 + 2;
    }
  }

  //print the spaces before the stars
  for (int i = 0; i < spacesBefore; i++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
  //print first part of stars
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfStars; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
  }
  //print spaces between the stars
  for (int i = 0; i < spacesBetween; i++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
  //print second part of stars
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfStars; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
  }
  //linebreak
  System.out.println();
}
```

In the middle section of the X-drawing, the `printPatternLine` is called multiple times, to print this amount of stars a total of four times for this call of the `patternMaker` method.

A short explanation of the `printPatternLine` method:

- The spaces before printing the stars and the spaces between the stars are calulated before
- The case for the middle section should be self-explaining (no spaces between, spaces before equal to the number of stars)
- For the non-middle part

  - The number of spaces before the stars relates to the position of the first stars for this line (for 1 * no space is printed, for 2 stars 1 space is printed, ...)
  - The number of spaces between the stars is 2 for the line which is one above the middle (1 space more on each side, 1 star more on each side). For every line that is one line farther away from the middle, the spaces in the middle increases by 4.

If you execute the `patternMaker` method with only one parameter by calling

```java
patternMaker(3);
```

it will print this pattern:

```
*          *
 **      **
  ***  ***
   ******
   ******
  ***  ***
 **      **
*          *
```

If you need spaces between the stars, multiply the number of spaces by 2 in front of the for loops and add one space to the star-output like this:

```java
private static void printPatternLine(int numOfStars, int max, boolean middle) {
  //...

  spacesBefore *= 2;
  spacesBetween *= 2;

  //...

  for (int i = 0; i < numOfStars; i++) {
    System.out.print("* ");
  }

  //...

  for (int i = 0; i < numOfStars; i++) {

    System.out.print("* ");
  }

  //...
}
```

Here is an example-output of `patternMaker(3);` with spaces:

```
*                     * 
  * *             * * 
    * * *     * * * 
      * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * 
    * * *     * * * 
  * *             * * 
*                     *
```

**Edit:** An adaption, if the middle part should contain more stars than the line before and after it, is easily possible.

Comment: Very nice explanation and code.Thank you!